# bs4 max result length

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a python script to scrape a news site with bs4 and I want to have the results on my 16x2 lcd screen. Is it possible to have something like a maximum length of soup.find_all results?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

r=urlopen("https://derstandard.at")
url = "https://derstandard.at"

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all("h2", limit=5):
    print(a.text)
```

This is the current script

Comment: Kindly add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking for but let me know if the following doesn't answer your question.

You're looking for a way to display the output (console) on your BIG screen/s.
Now while I'm not sure how to deal with this problem, you can probably use a specific IDE or change the *mode* of the console to be displayed on your big screen.

```
import os

os.system('mode con: cols=100 lines=40')
```

You can, of course, change the units to display bigger or wider results.

It would be helpful if you could edit your question to be a little bit more detailed or place a comment that I'm on the right track so I can help you, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt there is a special way to do this in BeatifulSoup and you really don't need one.

```
for a in soup.find_all("h2"):
    if len(a.text) <= 5:
        print(a.text)
```